# HTTP:CONNECTIVITY error to mule-worker-internal-myapp-region.cloudhub.io

Tags: mulesoft, mule4, cloudhub, anypoint-platform

I have a system-api (0.1vCore X 1 worker) hosted on private port. The http-listener configuration of system-api is:

```
<http:listener-config name="myapp-system-api-httpListenerConfig">
    <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="${http.private.port}" />
</http:listener-config>
```

I also have an experience-api in the same VPC, which consume services from this system-api using endpoint http://mule-worker-internal-myapp-region.cloudhub.io/api/. Normally this inter API connections works fine. For this process, none of the HTTP traffic routes through firewall.

During new release, when I re-deploy or re-start system-api, then API call from experience to system API results in 'HTTP:CONNECTIVITY' error. The connectivity between from experience to system API resumes successfully only after I restart experience-api.

I don't see this issue if I expose my system-api on ${http.port}.

Please could somebody confirm if this is normal? If yes, is this because my system-api is hosted on 1-worker?

Comment: what errors do you see? What do you mean by "expose my system-api on ${http.port}"? Please share the configurations that work and doesn't work. Be as specific as possible so others can help you. Provide reproduction steps and/or configurations/flows. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details.

Comment: are both APIs deployed on the same VPC? What firewall rules are active in the VPC?

Comment: @aled I think OP means that it does not happen when deployed on the public port (http.port) and only happening with private port

Comment: The OP should clarify exactly what ports they are using and provide other data for us to understand really the issue.

Comment: Raised this concern with support, this is mostly due to internal DNS caching. They provided an article for reference - https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/DNS-Resolution-Cache-In-Mule-Runtime-And-HTTP-Connector